Win10 Prof. (64bit) and old Agnitum Outpost 2 firewall ("engine Error loading driver 80")
I want to use my old well known firewall, which runs in XPSP3, but does not run - it runs, but the traffic does not go through this firewall - even in compatibility mode XPSP3.
It is possible to install, with or without Admin rights, with or without having the windows own firewall on or off, even without compatibility mode.
The firewall starts, the settings to do is possible, but after dial-in to the internet the firewall does not react.
I imagine there is a way to get it work somehow.
Thanks for reading, thanks the interesst.
Edit: After switching off the UAC confirmation it is possible to install without the compatibility mode. Is so possible to install easy and to do the settings.
But the traffic going through this firewall still does not work.
(Note. Firewall start error: "engine Error loading driver 80".)

No, there is NO way to do what you want and absolutely NO reason to even try.

You are trying to run an application that was 32-bit as a system component on a 64-bit operating system.  No way is going to work. Compatibility mode is a shim; it does not guarantee compatibility, especially with an old application. The application you are trying to use is NOT compatible with Windows 10.

A firewall is a software that needs to interact deeply with the networking layer of your OS. It probably contains driver software. It is unlikely that the compatibility modes can provide interfaces to make such a type of old software work with a modern version of Windows.

In compatibility mode 98_ME it runs and is correctly in the right place on the task-bar.
I never did use this firewall with public wlan hotspot connection.
And networks I am not really very familiar with.
This firewall works in XP with handy-tethering connection in XP and did it with usual broadband connection.
But with public WLAN hotspot ?
Thanks for reading.
